# OctoberCMS Backend User Permissions with Twig

Tags: php, twig, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) which uses [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

The way I retrieve user permissions is by getting the information in php then pass a twig variable.

Is there a way to do this using just Twig?

[Permissions Docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/users)

**PHP**

```
if (BackendAuth::check()) {
    # Get User Info
    $backend_user = BackendAuth::getUser();

    # Superuser
    $this['is_superuser'] = $backend_user->is_superuser;

    # Permissions
    $this['permissions_allow_edit'] = $backend_user->hasPermission(
    [
        'mycomponent.gallery.allow_edit'
    ]);
}
```

**Twig**

```
{% if is_superuser or permissions_allow_edit %}
    //edit button
{% endif %}
```

**Twig (Standalone)**

```
//another way to backendauth check in twig?
if (BackendAuth::check()) {
    $this['backend_user'] = BackendAuth::getUser(); 
}

//////

{% if backend_user.is_superuser or backend_user.permissions.mycomponent.gallery.allow_edit %}
    //edit button
{% endif %}
```

`{{ backend_user }}` gives the user information array

```
{"id":2,"first_name":"Matt","last_name":"","login":"matt","email":"user@example.com","permissions":{"mycomponent.gallery.allow_edit":1},"is_activated":false,"activated_at":null,"last_login":"2017-03-11 09:59:48","created_at":"2017-02-11 10:32:14","updated_at":"2017-03-11 10:03:45","is_superuser":0}
```

`{{ backend_user.permissions }}` throws an "Array to string conversion" error.

`{{ backend_user.permissions.mycomponent.gallery.allow_edit }}` shows nothing.

How do I get the values inside the permissions array?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but you should be able to use the `hasPermission` method to check if backend user has a specific permission:

```
{% if backend_user.is_superuser or backend_user.hasPermission('mycomponent.gallery.allow_edit') %}
    //edit button
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It did not seem to work, it returned null. But my permission is set, the twig variable 'permissions_allow_edit' returns 1.